# Get center of tableviewCell within coordinate system of superview of tableview

Tags: ios, cgpoint, superview

You can get the center point of a cell within the coordinates of its superview or tableView using:

```
  CGPoint center = cell.center;
```

If the tableview's superview is a UIView, how do you get the cell's center point within the coordinates of the superview of the tableview?

**Edit:**

The cell is in a tableView and the tableView is in self.view. I am mainly concerned about the y coordinate.  I did a test to see what the values should be but am not getting the desired result from convertPointToView:

```
//debugger values appear below each line
CGRect viewRect = self.view.frame;
//(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 568))
CGRect tableRect = self.tableView.frame;
//(origin = (x = 0, y = 108), size = (width = 320, height = 411))
 CGPoint prelimcenter = cell.center;
CGPoint center = prelimcenter;
//(x = 160, y = 242)
prelimcenter = [cell convertPoint:prelimcenter toView:self.view];
// (x = 160, y = 526)
```

I would expect the difference in the Y coordinate to be about 108 which is the difference in the frames.  However, the difference in the points using convertPoint is 284.  What could be wrong with my syntax/code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `convertPoint:toView:` method. Here's a link to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert).

```
CGPoint center = cell.center;
center = [cell convertPoint:center toView:yoursuperview];
```

That should convert it to the specified view's coordinate system.

Comment: Your answer makes sense but it is giving me the wrong result.  Would you mind taking a look at my edit and giving your opinion of what coudl be wrong?